# my 2 dimensional array row is not rotating

Tags: java, arrays, rotation, row

i'm trying to solve the problem of rotation of the row of the 2 dimensional array and i given below the input output details
after input of the 1
                   5 2
                   1 2 3 4 5 
i'm getting the output:-3 4 5 0 0
but the expected output is 3 4 5 1 2

```
package geeksforgeeks.basic;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RotationOfAnArray
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        //initializing the variables and the matrix
        int i, j, n, k, l, f, p;
        //taking the input
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] arr1 = new int[100][100];
        for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            k = sc.nextInt();
            l = sc.nextInt();
            for( j = 0; j < k; j++ )
            {
                arr1[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            //in the above section taking the input of the elements of the array of the matrix
            for( f = 0; f < l; f++ )
            {
                p = arr1[0][0];
                for( j = 0; j < arr1.length - 1; j++ )
                {
                    arr1[i][j] = arr1[i][j + 1];
                }
                //here the row of the particular matrix is not rotated
                arr1[i][arr1.length - 1] = p;
            }
            for( j = 0; j < k; j++ )
            {
                System.out.print( arr1[0][j] + "  " );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you have realized your mistake and solved your problem, I suggest you always put the message describing your input e.g. `System.out.print("Enter ...");` going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are initializing your array size as 100,and when later when you are trying to replace the last element by `arr1[i][arr1.length-1]=p;` it replaces last 99th index ,not 4th index. If you will iterate over complete array you can see those value sitting at last. My suggestion is initialise the array with the size of your need.
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class RotationOfAnArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
//initializing the variables and the matrix
int i,j,n,k,l,f,p;
//taking the input
n=sc.nextInt();
int[][] arr1;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
k=sc.nextInt();

//********Initialise array here instead.******
arr1=new int[k][k];


l=sc.nextInt();
for(j=0;j<k;j++){
arr1[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
}
//in the above section taking the input of the elements of the array of the matrix
for(f=0;f<l;f++) {
p=arr1[0][0];
for(j=0;j<arr1.length-1;j++) {
arr1[i][j]=arr1[i][j+1];
}
//here the row of the particular matrix is not rotated
arr1[i][arr1.length-1]=p;
}  
for(j=0;j<k;j++) {
System.out.print(arr1[0][j]+"  ");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: sir, i realize my mistake thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was that you were overwriting the array as you were iterating through it, here is an example using a one dimensional array.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
//initializing the variables and the matrix
int n,k,l;
//taking the input
n=sc.nextInt();//TestCases
k=sc.nextInt();//ArrayLength
l=sc.nextInt();//Rotations

int[] arr=new int[k];
for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
}//in the above section taking the input of the elements of the array of the matrix

//Rotating the array
int[] backupArr = new int[k];//Backup is made as not to overwrite array 
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
backupArr[((i+arr.length-l)%arr.length)]=arr[i];//Modulo is used to keep index within constraints of array
}
arr=backupArr;//array is set to rotated instance

for(int a : arr)System.out.print(a);
```